# Is there a name for functions whose derivatives only increase by a scalar when horizontally stretched?

Tags: calculus, functional-equations, transformation

I'm trying to figure out what families of functions would have a constant ratio in their derivatives when horizontally stretching or compressing. In other words:

$$ \frac{f'(x)}{f'(yx)} = z $$

where $z$ and $y$ are constants, and we are deriving with respect to $x$.

I noticed that $ln(x)$ and $\sqrt{x}$ follow that rule, having a ratio of derivative of $z = 1/y$ and $z=1/\sqrt{y}$, respectively. However, this rule does not seem to apply to every family of functions. For example, hyperbolic functions like the logistic map $ f(x) = 1/(1+e^x)$ does not follow that rule. In the hyperbolic case, $z$ is dependent on $e^x$.

Is there any way to find which functions would follow the above rule? Is anybody already given a name to functions that follow this  rule?

I am not a professional mathematician so I'm not familiar with the professional jargon, and I'm having trouble even finding a way to google for this rule.

Comment: Note that your examples all have $f'(x)\propto x^k$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: I agree, but I do not see how it relates to the question. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your examples are $f'$ satisfying the power law, but in general you have much more freedom than that --- given $y,z$ (say $y>1$) and any continuous function $g\colon [1,y]\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $g(y)=zg(1)$, you can extend $g$ to $\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $g(x)/g(yx)=z$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and hence $f(x)=f(1)+\int_1^x g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. The power law states $g(yx) = y^kg(x)$ while my rule is a more generic version of that. I also found that there's a name for this strict version of this property (scale-invariance). I will also keep in mind the rule you passed $g(y)=zg(1)$. It is much easier to test.

Would you like to put your comments as a answer, so you can get MSE reputation?